# Heroku routing/controller issue when going from dev to prod?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes

I am having an issue with going from local development to production on Heroku. Everything is working fine except my one 'new' action in my 'guestbook' controller. When I try to navigate to https://allbugsaside.herokuapp.com/guestbooks/new I get an error telling me to look at the logs. When I run Heroku logs, it doesn't tell me much except that a request was initiated.

I have a feeling I may be getting the issue because in my 'new' action I am calling .all on Guestbooks which currently does not have any data? Just a theory.

Can anyone assist in this problem? Thanks.

```
class GuestbooksController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @guestbooks = Guestbook.all
    end

    def new
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new
        @guestbooks = Guestbook.all
        @guestbooks = Kaminari.paginate_array(@guestbooks).page(params[:page]).per(5)
    end

    def create
        @guestbook = Guestbook.new(guestbook_params)
        # @guestbooks = Guestbook.all.limit(1).page(params[:page])

        if @guestbook.save
            flash.now[:notice] = "Thanks for taking the time to write us! We greatly appreciate it!"
            render :new
        else
            flash.now[:notice] = "Your message failed to post, please try again"
            render :new
        end
    end

    private
    def guestbook_params
        params.require(:guestbook).permit(:name, :email, :message)
    end
end
```

This is my new.html.erb

```
<h1 class="guestbook_head">Guestbook</h1><br/>

<div class="guestbook_text">
    <p>
        It is our goal to provide our customers with the best possible Pest Control Services and Solutions in the industry.

        Your comments and feedback are important to us.  They are a tool we use in order to keep on improving our experience, with you ….the customer. <br/><br/>
    </p>
</div>

<div class="paginate">
    <%= paginate @guestbooks %>
</div>

<div class="span1">
    <% @guestbooks.each do |g| %>
        <br/>
        <h4><%= g.name %>, <%= g.created_at %><br/></h4>
        <%= g.message %><br/>
        <p>-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------</p>
    <% end %>
</div>

<%= simple_form_for @guestbook, url: guestbooks_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    <div class="span2"><%= f.input :name %></div>
    <div class="span2"><%= f.input :email %></div>
    <div class="span3"><%= f.input :message %></div>
    <div class="span4"><%= f.button :submit %></div><br/><br/><br/>
<% end %>
```

These are my routes;

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pages, only: [:index] 
  get "/pages/home", to: "pages#home"
  get "/pages/about", to: "pages#about"
  get "/pages/pest_info", to: "pages#pest_info"
  get "/pages/annual_contracts", to: "pages#annual_contracts"
  get "/pages/monthly_info", to: "pages#monthly_info"
  get "/pages/snowplow", to: "pages#snowplow"
  get "/pages/gallery", to: "pages#gallery"
  resources :contact_form, only: [:new, :create]
  resources :guestbooks, only: [:new, :create]
  get "/guestbooks/index", to: "guestbooks#index"
  root "pages#home"
end
```

I am getting a 500 internal server error when I try to access the page.

```
2015-12-06T18:42:33.507953+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/pages/about" host=allbugsaside.herokuapp.com request_id=e07095da-734c-4fe3-aaa8-6f68d86a8e20 fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=5022
2015-12-06T18:42:40.331424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/guestbooks/new" host=allbugsaside.herokuapp.com request_id=134c9aab-f559-4e95-bad5-c1037dd38291 fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=1754
2015-12-06T18:42:40.390097+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/guestbooks/new" host=allbugsaside.herokuapp.com request_id=d552b372-80fa-4e76-83a3-371aa4f994ab fwd="96.248.110.224" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=500 bytes=1754
```

Comment: Index is available when you do `resources :guestbooks, only: [:new, :create, :index]` and by Rails conventions you will access to the index by the url: `/guestbooks` or in a `link_to` code inside any view: `guestbooks_path`.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Good catch on the code. Did not solve the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `heroku run rake db:migrate` in order to have your database updated? Of course, only if you did new migrations in your local environment. If this does not solve your problem, please post the logs from heroku.

Take in mind that Rails conventions make use of `index` (view and def in your controller) to display all the objects you want from certain model.

Here, you want to display them inside a `new`-object view. That is possible, just be careful. Is your view called `new.html.erb` ?

Also take in mind that `def new` is not an action, it is just a controller for your `new.html.erb` that provides data, variables, redirections and other stuff to the view called so.

Comment: I added my new.html.erb templated and routes file to this question. I have run heroku run rake db:migrate, to no avail. @JuanM.

Comment: I am not familiarised with simple form but try this: `<%= simple_form_for @guestbook do |f| %>` with no more parameters. In Rails 4, it is not necessary to specify the other things, as @guestbook is a new instance the submit button will lead the action to the create method.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed your page /guestbooks does not respond to the index action.  Could you post the routes.rb

Ruby is dynamic so technically:

```
 @guestbooks = Guestbook.all
 @guestbooks = Kaminari.paginate_array(@guestbooks).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

But I wouldn't do it.  Redefining a variable and using it as a reference to the declaration is as difficult to read as this sentence.

```
@guestbooks = Kaminari.paginate_array(Guestbook.all).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

If the problem exists in production and not in dev it isn't a problem with the code posted.  It isn't a problem with lacking data in the database, it could be a problem with the schema however.